# How do I search across sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, array-formulas

I want to transfer data automatically from 2 sheets to one single combining one. That means I have 2 different exports that contain both the columns "Problem". I have one sheet, that represents an overview of the data. So when I have for example the value `"A333"` in `A1` of my overview sheet, I want Excel to search in the two other export sheets the value `"A333"` and give back the value in the same row as `"A333"` but of the column `"Problem"` not `"A"`.

The problem that I see is that I have to search TWO sheets and I don't know in which one the `"A333"` will appear.

Can you please help me? I would preferably like to solve the problem with a formula, not a macro. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) write a formula (`VLOOKUUP()` for example) that looks for the value in the first sheet

2) write a formula that looks for the value in the second sheet

3)since VLOOKUP returns an ERROR if a value is not found you can combine the formulas together using `IFERROR()`. for example:  `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ref_cell,sheet1_range,2,0),VLOOKUP(ref_cell,sheet2_range,2,0))`

---

### EDIT:

It looks like you did not provide all the pertinent information in your question!
I suggested VLOOKUP(), but this will only work if you know which COLUMN the value you are looking for will appear in, but you said this is not the case...

using you comments I therefore assume the following:

- the two test sheets are called "test1" and "test2"
- The reference value we are looking for is in cell A5 on the main sheet, cell D1 on the sheet contains "Problem" (text)
- The reference value may appear anywhere (I limit here to range A1:J100) on test1 or test2, but ONLY ONCE
- The column "Product" on test1 and test2 may appear in different columns, but it will always have a heading "Product" in row 3 (test1!A3:J3 and test2!A3:J3)

see below of screenshot of the answer (column C shows result, column D shows the underlying formula)
If required use the information provided to create a single-cell formula (because Stack Overflow is not a we-write-the-answer-for-you service)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the idea sounds very good. Though my formula isn't working right now. My formula is right now: {=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A5,test1!A:J,MATCH(D$1,test1!A3:J3,0),0),(VLOOKUP($A5,test2!A:J,MATCH(D$1;test2!A3:J3,0),0)))} Do you see any mistakes? It appears #NV, even though there should be definitely a result!? @user3616725

Comment: show us what the "test" sheets actually look like - which columns are `A333` and `Problem` in ? and what is in `D1` that you are referring to?

Comment: So I have the sheet 'test 1' and the sheet 'test 2', which contain both the column 'Problem'.It can vary in which column exactly the 'Problem'-column is, thats why I'd like to search after the column that contains 'Problem'.Then I have one sheet, that represents an overview of the data that you can find in 'Test 1' and 'Test 2'. So when I have for example the value "A333" in A1 of my overview sheet, I want Excel to search in the two test-sheets the value 'A333' (wherever it will be positionated) and give back the value in the same row as 'A333' but of the column "Problem" not "A". @user3616725

Answer (score 0):

Following the scheme:

[image]

and add the formula:

```
E3 -> =CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3;$A$12:$B$15;2;FALSE);"");IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3;$A$3:$B$6;2;FALSE);""))
```

and autocomplete ...